# Unexpected value 'ng2 summernote'

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to use the summernote editor with Angular 2 and Webpack. I followed [this instructions](https://github.com/martinsvb/ng2-summernote) but it's not working and I'm having the "Unexpected value 'Ng2Summernote' declared by the module 'HomeModule'". How can I solve this?

Comment: My guess is that you did not define the `ng2-summernote` map path in your systemjs.config but can you share your config file and the component where you used the lib

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a systemjs.config.js. My config file is this one:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path    = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


// Webpack Config
var webpackConfig = {
entry: {
    'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
    'vendor'   : './src/vendor.browser.ts',
    'main'     : './src/main.browser.ts'
},

output: {
    path: './dist'
},

plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(true),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name     : ['main', 'vendor', 'polyfills'],
        minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        "require.specified": "require.resolve"
    })
],

module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test   : /\.ts$/,
            loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader')
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loaders: ["style", "css", "sass"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json'
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw-loader'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'
        },
        {
            test: /\.(eot|com|json|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream"
        },
        {
            test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'
        }
    ]
}

 };


// Our Webpack Defaults
var defaultConfig = {
devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
cache  : true,
debug  : true,
output : {
    filename         : '[name].bundle.js',
    sourceMapFilename: '[name].map',
    chunkFilename    : '[id].chunk.js'
},

resolve: {
    root      : [path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
    extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js']
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    watchOptions      : {aggregateTimeout: 300, poll: 1000}
},

node: {
    global        : 1,
    crypto        : 'empty',
    module        : 0,
    Buffer        : 0,
    clearImmediate: 0,
    setImmediate  : 0
  }
  };

   var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
   module.exports   = webpackMerge(defaultConfig, webpackConfig);
```